# Как сделать фильтрацию с помощью <select> и выводить результат в новый блок?

Tags: html, jquery, select

Всем привет !
У меня возник трудный вопрос, вот код

```
    "https://jsfiddle.net/fardo000/b0sv45jy/3/"

    <select id="filter">
      <option value="item">все</option>
      <option value="red">красный</option>
      <option value="blue">синий</option>
      <option value="green">зелёный</option>
      <option value="orange">оранжевый</option>
      <option value="yellow">жёлтый</option>
    </select>

<div class="filters">
   <div class="filters-size">
      <span>Размер</span>
        <select class="" name="size">
         <option value="56">56</option>
         <option value="58">58</option>
         <option value="60">60</option>
         <option value="62">62</option>
      </select>
      </div>
 <button class="btn btn_access"> Применить фильтр</button>
 </div>
    <div id="items">
      <div class="item red54">1</div>
      <div class="item blue">2</div>
      <div class="item red 60">3</div>
      <div class="item green">4</div>
      <div class="item red 60">5</div>
      <div class="item orange">6</div>
      <div class="item green">7</div>
      <div class="item yellow 56">8</div>
      <div class="item green">9</div>
      <div class="item orange">10</div>
      <div class="item yellow">11</div>
      <div class="item blue54">12</div>
      <div class="item green">13</div>
      <div class="item orange 56">14</div>
      <div class="item blue 60">15</div>
      <div class="item orange 56">16</div>
      <div class="item red 54">17</div>
      <div class="item yellow">18</div>
    </div>
```

помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, у меня работает сейчас только первый select, и он только фильтрует блоки по цвету.

Вопрос состоит в том, как сделать так чтобы сначала выбрать все необходимые фильтры которые нам нужны и тогда когда нажимаешь кнопку применить фильтр все блоки которые есть они остались, а результат по фильтру показать над этим списком блока?

Если кто то с этим сталкивался или есть какие то примеры кода, буду очень Благодарен.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function applyFilters() {
  var color = $("#filter-color").val();
  var size = $("#filter-size").val();
  var selector = "#items ." + color + "." + size;

  $("#results").empty().append($(selector).clone());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters">

  <span>Color</span>
  <select id="filter-color">
    <option value="item">все</option>
    <option value="red">красный</option>
    <option value="blue">синий</option>
    <option value="green">зелёный</option>
    <option value="orange">оранжевый</option>
    <option value="yellow">жёлтый</option>
  </select>

  <span>Размер</span>
  <select class="" id="filter-size">
    <option value="56">56</option>
    <option value="58">58</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="62">62</option>
  </select>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn_access" onclick="applyFilters()">Применить фильтр</button>
</div>


<span>All</span>
<div id="items">
  <div class="item red 54">1</div>
  <div class="item blue">2</div>
  <div class="item red 60">3</div>
  <div class="item green">4</div>
  <div class="item red 60">5</div>
  <div class="item orange">6</div>
  <div class="item green">7</div>
  <div class="item yellow 56">8</div>
  <div class="item green">9</div>
  <div class="item orange">10</div>
  <div class="item yellow">11</div>
  <div class="item blue 54">12</div>
  <div class="item green">13</div>
  <div class="item orange 56">14</div>
  <div class="item blue 60">15</div>
  <div class="item orange 56">16</div>
  <div class="item red 54">17</div>
  <div class="item yellow">18</div>
</div>

<span>Results</span>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Comment: Агоньььь !! Спасибо большое !

Comment: @nazzfardo На здоровье. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.